# Specify location from which a line starts in pstricks

Tags: positioning, pstricks, pst-node

I have a problem with the following code. The lines from h6 and h7 are supposed to start right below h6 and h7 and not at the left of h6 and h7. This worked with tree-dvips but `pstricks` seems to decide differently about the position where the line starts. Is it possible to force `pstricks` to take bottom instead of bottom left?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}


\psset{nodesep=5pt} %,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowscale=2}
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
                               & \rnode{h0}{h0}                & \\[8ex]
\rnode{h1}{h1:every(x, \rnode{h1h3}{h2}, \rnode{h1h2}{h3})}      &                              & \rnode{h5}{h5:some(y, \rnode{h5h7}{h6}, \rnode{h5h6}{h7})}\\[8ex]
\rnode{h3}{h2:dog(x)}           & ~~~~~\rnode{h7}{h6:cat(y)}         & \\[6ex]
                               & \rnode{h4}{h4:chase(e, x, y)}\\
\end{tabular}
{\psset{linestyle=dashed}%
\ncline{h0}{h5}%
\ncline{h0}{h1}%
\ncline{h5h6}{h4}%
\ncline{h1h2}{h4}%
}%
\ncline{h1h3}{h3}%
\ncline[angleA=-90]{h5h7}{h7}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default location for the anchor in an `\rnode` is in the centre of the node. With the notation `\rnode[<refpoint>]{<name>}{<stuff>}` (see the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf), section **30 Nodes**, p 59) you can specify an alternative `<refpoint>`, say `[b]` (section **24 Placing and rotating whatever**, p 42):

[image]

I've also decreased the `nodesepA` value (the node separation from the origin node) to `3pt` to make it clear that it's pointing to the correct node:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pstricks,pst-node}

\psset{nodesep=5pt,linewidth=0.5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
  & \rnode{h0}{h0} & \\[8ex]
  \rnode{h1}{h1:every(x, \rnode{h1h3}{h2}, \rnode{h1h2}{h3})} & & \rnode{h5}{h5:some(y, \rnode[b]{h5h7}{h6}, \rnode[b]{h5h6}{h7})} \\[8ex]
  \rnode{h3}{h2:dog(x)} & ~~~~~\rnode{h7}{h6:cat(y)} & \\[6ex]
  & \rnode{h4}{h4:chase(e, x, y)} \\
  \end{tabular}
{\psset{linestyle=dashed}%
 \ncline{h0}{h5}%
 \ncline{h0}{h1}%
 \ncline[nodesepA=3pt]{h5h6}{h4}%
 \ncline{h1h2}{h4}%
}%
\ncline{h1h3}{h3}%
\ncline[nodesepA=3pt]{h5h7}{h7}%

\end{document}​
```